# How to Deal with multiple time zones in Application?

Tags: ios, timezone

like eg. in which format we need to Store and fetch dates? should it will be stored on Server Time? or All Dates Should store in Specific one Time zone ? Didn't know how deal with it.

Comment: You would normally store dates in UTC and then you can adjust to the local timezone on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to convert UTC to Device Local timezone.If your server timezone is Indian then use "IST" abbreviation instead of "UTC".

```
extension String{
func convertUTCToLocalDate(inputFormat: String, outputFormat: String)-> String{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = inputFormat
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let oldDate = formatter.date(from: self)
    formatter.dateFormat = outputFormat
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current 
    return (oldDate != nil) ? formatter.string(from: oldDate!) : self
}}
```

Usage:-

```
let localDate = "20 Jul, 2018".convertUTCToLocalDate(inputFormat: "dd MMM, yyyy", outputFormat: "dd MMM, yyyy")
```